# Filter SQL Data on HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to find a way to filter my sql data from a mysql database on my html table. The trouble I've had is because it's a dynamic table. Should I be sorting on the html table, and if so, how do I get the result html from the sql query (the entire table), as opposed to the html that's just a single row.

If I need to sort on the SQL query itself, how can I do this without needing to refresh the page every time?

Thanks for any help!

Here's my code for reference:

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
// OREDER BY id DESC is order result by descending
}
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<table id="forum" width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>
<th width="43%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<th width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Author</strong></td>
<th width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>
<th width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>
<th width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php 

// Start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['threadtype']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><? echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody
<?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
}
mysql_close();
?>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="right" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="create_topic.php"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of data [less than 100 rows], it is reasonable to load the entire thing with one query and do all the sorting/filtering client-side.

There are tons of great jquery plugins for doing this.  Here is a good one I like:

https://datatables.net/

If you want to be scaleable and handle a lot of rows then you don't want to just load all of them at once.

In this case you want to implement a paging pattern with your queries.  If you need to do paging then you will also need your query to sort on the backend when the user changes which column they want to sort by.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, especially if you don't feel comfortable rolling your own here, there are lots of tools you can use to do this.  This one seems promising: http://blog.drale.com/mysql-table-viewer-with-pagination-and-sorting/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had looked into the Datatables plugin, but I'm planning on having a large table. The second link you posted looks exactly like what I'm looking for.